# NuxtJS/Laravel 8 + Sanctum

Tags: laravel, session, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

How to auth in production via Session/Cookie

Nuxt (NuxtAuth - Laravel Sanctum Provider, SPA)
Laravel (8.0 + Sanctum)

It works on:

**Nuxt** -  localhost:3000

**Laravel** -  localhost:8000

**My Production Config**

Laravel: **api.domain.com**

NuxtJS(SPA): **domain.com**

.env

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=domain.com, api.domian.com
SESSION_DOMAIN=api.domain.com
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
APP_URL=https://api.domian.com
```

config/cors.php

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login'],
```

config/sanctum.php

```
'guard' => ['api'], //default ‘web’
```

config/session.php

```
'same_site' => "None", //default Lax
```

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web'     => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api'     => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'sanctum' => [
            'driver'   => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
  protected $middlewareGroups = [
       'api' => ['stateful', 'throttle', 'bindings'],
       'spa' => ['stateful', 'throttle', 'bindings'],
    ];
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function()
{
    Route::get('/api/user', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
}
```

app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

Finally

GET  /sanctum/csrf-cookie Response 204
POST /login Response 200 With X-CSRF-TOKEN, Set-Cookie Header

but..

Unauthenticated on GET /api/user

Please, help